# Pyspark DataFrame from given input text

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a text file which contains the below formatted data:

```
'a:1,b:1,d:1,e:1,h:1'
'a:2,e:2,d:2,h:2,f:2'
'c:3,e:3,d:3,h:3,f:3'
'a:4,b:4,c:4,e:4,h:4,f:4,i:4,j:4'
```

Expected output:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j 
1|1| |1|1| |1|1| | 
2| | |2|2|2| |2| | 
 | |3|3|3|3| |3| | 
4|4|4| |4|4| |4|4|4
```

Comment: Input.txt 
a:1,b:1,d:1,e:1,h:1 
a:2,e:2,d:2,h:2,f:2  
c:3,e:3,d:3,h:3,f:3 
a:4,b:4,c:4,e:4,h:4,f:4,i:4,j:4
                                                                                                                                            
Expected output: 
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j 
1|1| |1|1| |1|1| | 
2| | |2|2|2| |2| | 
 | |3|3|3|3| |3| | 
4|4|4| |4|4| |4|4|4

Comment: Could clarify whether you expect the first row: `a|b|c|...` to be a header column? Or is that first row a row of data itself.

Comment: yes , its a header column or you can say field name